# Can I setup my domain so that some subdirectories/pages point to one server, while others point to another server?

Tags: dns, jekyll, github-pages

My domain is qrohlf.com. It used to be hosted via Dreamhost and have a wordpress installation on it, along with various custom experiments in subdirectories (i.e. qrohlf.com/experiment-name/index.html)

This was nice because I could have my blog, but could also easily toss experiments on my top-level domain.

I have since moved my blog to the Jekyll platform hosted on github pages. I've got the basic setup, with a top-level A record pointing to the pages server IP. However, this breaks any links to my experiments, which are still hosted on the Dreamhost server.

Is there any way that http://qrohlf.com/experiment-name can point to my Dreamhost IP, but http://qrohlf.com and http://qrohlf.com/posts/example-post/ can still be served via Github pages?

Comment: I don't think there is. You could move your experimts to a subdomain tho, and have that pointed somewhere else, and then set up meta-redirects on the subdirectories of your gh-page.

Comment: probably what I'm going to do, or move the Jekyll install to my server. This is definitely a case of simplicity vs configurability.